# How to access elements of an object created using vector

Tags: c++

I was trying to create objects to a class dynamically using vector.

```
class lib
{
    int a;
};
```

THen using this to make objects.

```
vector<lib> book;
book.resize(n);  //n is the number of objects.
```

So I am trying this to access 'a' from the class.

```
book[0].a= something;
```

This doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?
I am getting runtime error.

Comment: maybe move to SO? But even if you ask on SO you should post enough of your code so the problem is _reproducible_. Also, what does not work? Compile-errors? Wrong results? What do you expect? What do you get? From a code review point of view I'd say your class is a book. A vector of books then could be seen as a lib. (Rather than the other way around as you have it here.)

Comment: The member `a` is private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `book[0].a= something;` only if `lib` becomes a `struct` (instead of a `class`) or if you make `a` public.

You can also create accessors (`int getA() const;` `void setA(int);`) and call `book[0].setA(something);`

Comment: I tried making 'a' public and using accessors. Both of them did not work.
Using struct instead of class is also not working.

Comment: Did you check that n is not 0 ? If it's a runtime error there's a good chance is that what the problem is. Use a debugger or print the value to ensure that n is not 0.